# Bulk update using model's method in SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I'm developing an application with SQLAlchemy and I've run into a bit of an issue. I would like to run a method on all models returned by a query and make all that in a single SQL query, while preserving the readability the ORM offers.

The method in question is very simple and doesn't depend on any external data nor makes any more queries. It's also fine if all the models in the bulk update use the same exact value, so the value itself needs to be evaluated only once.

Here's my model:

```
class Item(db.Model):
    last_fetch = db.Column(db.DateTime)

    def refresh(self):
        self.last_fetch = datetime.utcnow()
```

I would like to call the `refresh()` function on all models returned by a query - for the sake of example let's assume it's `Item.query.all()`.

I can iterate through them and run the method on each model but that would run a separate query for each one of them:

```
items = Item.query.all()

for item in items:
    item.refresh()
```

Or I could do the following which works however I've now moved my `refresh()` logic from the model to the code that would otherwise just call that method:

```
items = Item.query.all()

items.update({Item.last_fetch: datetime.utcnow()})
```

Is there a better solution? A way to define a "smart" method on the model that would somehow allow the ORM to run it in bulk while still keeping it a model method?

Regards.

Answer (score 0):

Since SQLAlchemy doesn't recreate queried objects using `__init__` but `__new__`.
You could either override `__new__` on your model or  try and see if the `@orm.reconstructor` decorator explained in [Constructors and Object Initialization](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/constructors.html) would work.

Using the reconstructor:

```
class Item(db.Model):
last_fetch = db.Column(db.DateTime)

@orm.reconstructor
def set_last_fetch_on_load(self):
    self.last_fetch = datetime.datetime.now()
```

Overriding `__new__`:

```
class Item(db.Model):
last_fetch = db.Column(db.DateTime)

def __new__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
    obj = object.__new__(cls, *args, **kwargs)
    obj.last_fetch = datetime.datetime.now()
    return obj
```

**Note:** Haven't tested it.

Comment: Wouldn't this cause the date to reset every time the model is instantiated? That's not what I want. I want to be able to trigger that manually (I only call this under specific conditions).

Comment: It would update the date every time you query the items. So every time you fetch them from the database. If you only need to do this under specific conditions - i think that what you've written would work and you can disregard my answer.